# issue with image ng-repeat .error in console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ionic-framework

I am getting unexpected issue in my ng-repeat of image . i just want to show image and pdf based on its type .  **[

> [[image: I am getting this error on my app]]

My codepen is
**codepen.io/anujsphinx/pen/GNepPE**

I am getting error in console,Please check that issue

my code is

```
<div ng-repeat="media in docList" class="list">
           <div class="item item-avatar"  ng-if="media.docType == 'image'">
              <img  ng-src="{{media.docUrl}}">
              <h3>{{media.docName}}</h3> {{media.docUrl}}
           </div>
            <div class="item item-avatar" ng-click="Download({{media.docUrl}})" ng-if="media.docType == 'pdf'">
              <img  ng-src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/file-extensions-1/64/pdfs-512.png" type='application/pdf'>
              <h3>{{media.docName}}</h3>{{media.docUrl}}
           </div>
        </div>
```

js

```
  $scope.docList = [
            {id:1,docName: 'pic1.jpg',docUrl : 'http://3.bp.blogspot.com/-XchURXRz-5c/U5ApPOrPM9I/AAAAAAAADoo/YZEj4qeSlqo/s1600/Final-Fantasy-XV-Noctis-Red-Eyes.png' ,docType :'image'}, 
            {id:3,docName: 'dummy.pdf',docUrl : 'http://werkspoorkathedraal.nl/user-files/uploads/2015/02/dummy_pdf.pdf' ,docType :'pdf'}
            ];
```

Comment: I suggest you provide your view and controller, rather than linking to a third party website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you need to understand that different angular directive take different arguments

while ng-src take an template Interpolation {{}} as argument , ngclick takes expression as an argument so you need not to specify {{}} in ng-click.

Read more here.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngSrc

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngClick

so the code should be written as

```
<div class="item item-avatar" ng-click="Download(media.docUrl)" ng-if="media.docType == 'pdf'">
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this, may be it helps,

```
<div ng-repeat="media in docList" class="list">
       <div class="item item-avatar"  ng-if="media.docType == 'image'">
          <img  ng-src="{{media.docUrl}}">
          <h3>{{media.docName}}</h3> {{media.docUrl}}
       </div>
        <div class="item item-avatar" ng-click="Download(media.docUrl)" ng-if="media.docType == 'pdf'">
          <img  ng-src="https://cdn4.iconfinder.com/data/icons/file-extensions-1/64/pdfs-512.png" type='application/pdf'>
          <h3>{{media.docName}}</h3>{{media.docUrl}}
       </div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like your error lies on line 27 in your HTML. Change it to read:

`<div class="item item-avatar" ng-click="Download(media.docUrl)" ng-if="media.docType == 'pdf'">`

Answer (score 0):

In ng-click never use {{}}

`ng-click="Download({{media.docUrl}})"`  should be `ng-click="Download(media.docUrl)"`